# jQuery adds rows to table that aren't in my html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I use jQuery to append rows to a html table, it is adding an extra row that isn't in my html string, see below the code:

```js
var stringTable = '<thead><tr><th class="sr-only">Row Index</th><th>Column 0</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>List Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th><tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="sr-only">0</td><td>A & B</td><td>143 AVE</td><td></td><td>AMAZON</td><td>EU</td><td>List 1</td><td></td><td></td><tr></tbody>';
        $(stringTable).appendTo('.table');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"></table>
```

Is it a jQuery bug? How can I solve it?

Comment: The code you've pasted above seems to be running fine. Is there any extra info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the very first tr but reopened it at the end. There simple is the "/" missing in the  ;)

Comment: Oh my god, it was my fault. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

sintax errors in yours html...

Add small html, like this:

```
     var head_stringTable = '<thead><tr><th class="sr-only">Row Index</th><th>Column 0</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>List Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th></tr></thead>';
     var body_stringTable = '<tbody></tbody>';
     $('.table').append(head_stringTable);
     $('.table').append(body_stringTable);
     var table_body=$('.table').find('tbody');
     var table_row='<tr><td class="sr-only">0</td><td>A & B</td><td>143 AVE</td><td></td><td>AMAZON</td><td>EU</td><td>List 1</td><td></td><td></td><tr>';
     table_body.append(table_row);
```

full snippet:

```js
     var head_stringTable = '<thead><tr><th class="sr-only">Row Index</th><th>Column 0</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>List Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th></tr></thead>';
     var body_stringTable = '<tbody></tbody>';
     $('.table').append(head_stringTable);
     $('.table').append(body_stringTable);
     var table_body=$('.table').find('tbody');
     
     var table_row='<tr><td class="sr-only">0</td><td>A & B</td><td>143 AVE</td><td></td><td>AMAZON</td><td>EU</td><td>List 1</td><td></td><td></td><tr>';
     
     table_body.append(table_row);
     
     var table_row='<tr><td class="sr-only">0</td><td>C & B</td><td>146 AVE</td><td></td><td>AMAZON</td><td>US</td><td>List 2</td><td></td><td></td><tr>';
     
     table_body.append(table_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"></table>
```